# Convert dataframe String column to Array[Int]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, functional-programming

I am new to Scala and Spark and I am trying to read a csv file locally (for testing):

```
val spark = org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("Spark CSV Reader").getOrCreate;
val topics_df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load("path-to-file.csv")
topics_df.show(10)
```

Here's how the file looks like:

```
+-----+--------------------+--------------------+
|topic|         termindices|         termweights|
+-----+--------------------+--------------------+
|   15|[21,31,51,108,101...|[0.0987100701,0.0...|
|   16|[42,25,121,132,55...|[0.0405490884,0.0...|
|    7|[1,23,38,7,63,0,1...|[0.1793091892,0.0...|
|    8|[13,40,35,104,153...|[0.0737646511,0.0...|
|    9|[2,10,93,9,158,18...|[0.1639456608,0.1...|
|    0|[28,39,71,46,123,...|[0.0867449145,0.0...|
|    1|[11,34,36,110,112...|[0.0729913664,0.0...|
|   17|[6,4,14,82,157,61...|[0.1583892199,0.1...|
|   18|[9,27,74,103,166,...|[0.0633899386,0.0...|
|   19|[15,81,289,218,34...|[0.1348582482,0.0...|
+-----+--------------------+--------------------+
```

with

```
ReadSchema: struct<topic:string,termindices:string,termweights:string>
```

The `termindices` column is supposed to be of type `Array[Int]`, but when saved to CSV it is a `String` (This usually would not be a problem if I pull from databases).

How do I convert the type and eventually cast the DataFrame to a:

```
case class TopicDFRow(topic: Int, termIndices: Array[Int], termWeights: Array[Double])
```

I have the function ready to perform the conversion:

```
termIndices.substring(1, termIndices.length - 1).split(",").map(_.toInt)
```

I have looked at `udf` and a few other solutions but I am convinced that there should be a much cleaner and faster way to perform said conversion. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Read it in as text file and use map on the red then finally createDataFrame with your schema

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UDFs should be avoided when it's possible to use the more efficient in-built Spark functions. To my knowledge there is no better way than the one proposed; remove the first and last characters of the string, split and convert.

Using the in-built functions, this can be done as follows:

```
df.withColumn("termindices", split($"termindices".substr(lit(2), length($"termindices")-2), ",").cast("array<int>"))
  .withColumn("termweights", split($"termweights".substr(lit(2), length($"termweights")-2), ",").cast("array<double>"))
  .as[TopicDFRow]
```

`substr` if 1-index based so to remove the first character we start from 2. The second argument is the length to take (not the end point) hence the `-2`.

The last command will cast the dataframe to a dataset of type `TopicDFRow`.